# Specifying default value of SelectDateWidget in a ModelForm?

Tags: django-forms, modelform

Is there a method of specifying a default value to `SelectDateWidget` when used in a `ModelForm`?

Such that when the webpage is rendered it defaults to todays date.
(I know that this is possible with a user form, passing the initial value. However I need to use a `ModelForm` so that users can edit existing event instances.

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
import datetime

from .models import Event

class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['title', 'date_of']
        labels = {'title': '', 'date_of': ''}
        widgets = {'date_of': forms.SelectDateWidget()}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an argument in DateWidget that you can use. But doing this with `default` argument in your model field would be better.

`initial=datetime.now()`

You will need to import datetime also with `from datetime import datetime`

Comment: I swear I had tried that and it hadn't made any change when reloading the page. Tried again just now, and bam! Thank you very much.